# PlayFramework scala template generic types cause error: ']' expected but eof found. And error: identifier expected but $XMLSTART$< found

Tags: java, scala, templates, generics, playframework-2.2

I am trying add to **scala** **templates** some generic variables from **java**, but unfortunately no luck so far.

I am **not a scala specialist**. I am only daily **Java Developer**.

I've choose Play, cause seemed to as an easy one framework in Java world.
Now I have problems with this scala templates.

I've founded in [scala tutorial](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html) that I've to add `plus` char to defines extension.

Here is my code:

Entity class:

```
public class Insurance<T> {
    // some code
}
```

List declaration (did not declare the type argument here):

```
List<Entity> entities = new LinkedList<Entity>();
```

Passing parameters to view template render method:

```
return ok(views.html.Index.render(entities));
```

And on Scala View layer:

```
@(entities: List[models.Entity[+T]])
```

But I am getting an errors:

```
[error] /home/app/views/Index.scala.html:0: identifier expected but $XMLSTART$< found.
[error] /home/app/views/Index.scala.html:150: ']' expected but eof found.
```

When I will remove generics it will work.

Please help.

Comment: What is the relations between your `Entity` class and `Insurance` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template is actually just like a method, being just like a method the parameter list `(entities: List[models.Entity[+T]])` isn't any more valid than `public Something myTemplate(entities: List[models.Entity[+T]])`, there just isn't any place to put a type parameter to the method call, therefore you must provide a concrete type instead of `T`.

Additionally in Scala the variance of the type parameter (the `+`) isn't specified at the call site, but in the declaration, so it wouldn't be valid even if you could define the type parameter in the method signature.

What you might be able to do is to just say it could be anything, using `models.Entity[Any]` or possibly just that you do not care using `models.Entity[_]` (basically like `models.Entity<?>` in Java).

As a side note it seems like might be something you should think about once or twice extra just from the fact that if you could use a totally unbound type parameter `T` then that means you do not know anything about it inside of the template and if you don't know anything about it what would you do with it in a template?

Hope this helps!